# CAS integration with multiple OpenID Providers

Tags: azure-active-directory, cas, google-client-login

We are in process of integrating CAS with multiple openID providers, For example with Azure and Google.
Can anyone help me with the configurations?

Suppose we have User1 and User2.

1)Whenever user1 acesses the application URL, he has to be redirected to google login page,

2) Whenever  user2 acesses the application URL, he has to be redirected to microsoft Azure login page.

Comment: You could use the Azure AD B2C to add google as a provider. For the details, you could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-goog-app).

Comment: Hi Thanks for the quick response, let me give an example for my requirement, 

We are in process of integrating CAS with multiple openID providers, For example with Azure and Google. Can anyone help me with the configurations?

Suppose we have User1 and User2.

1)Whenever user1 acesses the application URL, he has to be redirected to google login page,

2) Whenever user2 acesses the application URL, he has to be redirected to microsoft Azure login page.

Comment: In the Azure AD B2C, upon entering the app url,  the user will need to manually choose the provider, like google or microsoft azure.

Comment: What are you asking? How to do it? What have you tried?

Comment: @SunnySun, we want it to auto direct to particular provider based on client name.

Comment: @GertvandenBerg, When I configure only one provider in cas.properties, the redirection to the provider Login page everytime the application URL is hit works fine.

Comment: @GertvandenBerg, When I configure multiple providers in cas.properties like, cas.authn.pac4j.oidc[0].type=GOOGLE
cas.authn.pac4j.oidc[0].discoveryUri=https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration
cas.authn.pac4j.oidc[1].type=AZURE
cas.authn.pac4j.oidc[1].discoveryUri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/08123ccas.authn.pac4j.oidc[1].clientName=AzureClient,    the redirection fails.

Comment: @SunnySun, we want it to auto direct to particular provider based on client name. When I configure only one provider in cas.properties, the redirection to the provider Login page everytime the application URL is hit works fine. When I configure multiple providers in cas.properties like, cas.authn.pac4j.oidc[0].type=GOOGLE cas.authn.pac4j.oidc[0].discoveryUri=accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration cas.authn.pac4j.oidc[1].type=AZURE cas.authn.pac4j.oidc[1].discoveryUri=login.microsoftonline.com/…, the redirection fails.